# SSAS - Passing MDX Report Parameter to MDX DataSet Query

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, olap-cube

In my MDX report based on cube, the input help for date must be a calendar, therefore Date/Time type of parameter is essential. The field in time dimension by which I filter data is Integer. Example value: 20130827.

My dataset query looks like this:

```
 SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Hours In Track] } ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY {
 ([Dim Date].[Date ID].[Date ID].ALLMEMBERS * [Dim Division].[Hierarchy].[Division ID].ALLMEMBERS ) }
 DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM
 ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@DimDivisionHierarchy, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM
 ( SELECT ( STRTOMEMBER(@FromDimDateDateID, CONSTRAINED) : STRTOMEMBER(@ToDimDateDateID, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM [BicepsArveCube]))
 CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

I used a text field, which showed me, that date/time type parameter value looks as follows: 
2013-08-05 00:00:00, while my DateID is Integer type, so I need to do conversion.

When in dataset parameters tab I specify the parameter value as expression:

```
="[Dim Date].[Date ID].&["
 & Replace(Replace("2013-08-05 00:00:00", "-", ""), " 00:00:00", "")
 & "]"
```

I get the data as expected, everything works fine. But when I changed the hardcoded date/time value to parameter value (type date/time ):

```
="[Dim Date].[Date ID].&["
 & Replace(Replace(Parameters!FromDimDateDateID.Value, "-", ""), " 00:00:00", "")
 & "]"
```

I get a constraint violation error. I don't know why, because as written above, the `Parameters!FromDimDateDateID.Value` looks exactly the same as the hardcoded value I used.

I used text field to check what expression I get after conversion in both cases (hardcoded date and the same date chosen from calendar and passed as parameter value) and it looks exactly the same:

```
[Dim Date].[Date ID].&[20130805]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
STRTOMEMBER(
  "[Dim Date].[Date ID].&["
 + Replace(Replace(@FromDimDateDateID, "-", ""), " 00:00:00", "")
 + "]",
CONSTRAINED)
```

In MDX - which is interpreted by Analysis Services - you cannot access Reporting Services objects like `Parameters`. Instead, their value is sent to the Analysis Services server along with the MDX statement, which can reference them with the `@` notation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for response, but after implementing your idea, while trying to execute query, I got error message "The following system error occured: Access is denied".

Comment: Can you determine from the message if the message is from SSRS or SSAS? DO you have full access to all parts of the cube, or are there access restrictions in place in the cube?

Comment: This error comes from Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Analysis Services. There are no access restrictions set, and I checked all possible roles, priviliges etc. I could, still having same error :(

Comment: @ArturChmielewski Re-reading your original post, I am not sure if I was completely misunderstanding it as someone with deep understanding of Analysis Services and only superficial knowledge of Reporting Services. Maybe the `CONSTRAINED violation` is not an error in the sense that the code is wrong, but is just saying that the member that you constructed does not exist in the cube. Did you check that the date that you tried is contained in the cube? If you re-try your original solution with a date that definitely exists in the cube, does it work? Also, you could try omitting the `,CONSTRAINED`.

Comment: Problem solved... it was the matter of Replace... it seems date/time type has some mysterious hidden characters, which you need to know if you wanna replace them :) . I used <code>CInt(Format(parameter_value, "yyyyMMdd")</code> and it works fine